# Cannot install ember on ubuntu 1404

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ember.js

I've installed nodejs and npm on my ubuntu. Then I installed ember on my machine and I typed `ember -v` to verify that ember has installed successfully. But I got the following message from the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I have accidently installed node (instead of nodejs) but then I removed it... now when I type `node` in terminal, it gives me:

```
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:

 * node

 * nodejs-legacy
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

what I have to do to install ember properly?

Answer (score 10):

Run

```
which nodejs
```

in my case it displayed /usr/bin/nodejs

Make a link

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
```

it should work afterwards